# Segmentation fault on tf2_ros

Tags: ros, ros2, tf2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using slam_toolbox with arm64 architecture.
But I encount SIGSEGV.

How do I fix this error?

backtrace:

```
  #0  tf2_ros::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> >, tf2_ros::Buffer>::transformReadyCallback (this=0x555589d120, future=..., handle=2109) at /opt/ros/rolling/include/tf2_ros/message_filter.h:498
  #1  0x0000007fb721d0a8 in ?? () from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2_ros.so
  #2  0x0000007fb6f313f4 in tf2::BufferCore::testTransformableRequests() () from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2.so
  #3  0x0000007fb6f323d4 in tf2::BufferCore::setTransformImpl(tf2::Transform const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) ()
 from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2.so
 #4  0x0000007fb6f33354 in tf2::BufferCore::setTransform(geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) ()
 from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2.so
 #5  0x0000007fb7228df8 in tf2_ros::TransformListener::subscription_callback(std::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > >, bool) () from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2_ros.so
 #6  0x0000007fb72302c0 in std::_Function_handler<void (std::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > >), std::_Bind<void (tf2_ros::TransformListener::*(tf2_ros::TransformListener*, std::_Placeholder<1>, bool))(std::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > >, bool)> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, std::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > >&&) () from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2_ros.so
 #7  0x0000007fb72414c0 in rclcpp::AnySubscriptionCallback<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::dispatch(std::shared_ptr<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> > >, rclcpp::MessageInfo const&) () from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2_ros.so
 #8  0x0000007fb7241da4 in rclcpp::Subscription<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void>, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >::handle_message(std::shared_ptr<void>&, rclcpp::MessageInfo const&) ()
 from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2_ros.so
 #9  0x0000007fb79a76bc in ?? () from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/librclcpp.so
 #10 0x0000007fb79a82a8 in rclcpp::Executor::execute_subscription(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::SubscriptionBase>) ()
 from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/librclcpp.so
 #11 0x0000007fb79a8ad4 in rclcpp::Executor::execute_any_executable(rclcpp::AnyExecutable&) ()
 from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/librclcpp.so
 #12 0x0000007fb79b1f34 in rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor::spin() ()
 #13 0x0000007fb722843c in ?? () from /opt/ros/rolling/lib/libtf2_ros.so
 #14 0x0000007fb772dc2c in ?? () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
 #15 0x0000007fb73d04fc in start_thread (arg=0x7fffffb98f) at pthread_create.c:477
 #16 0x0000007fb759d67c in thread_start () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/clone.S:78
```

I guess that these lines are incorrect.
https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/1354c5663139e50ecafb888ae15aa113e9c3985d/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/message_filter.h#L486
Because messages_ may be accessed before take the lock.

Am I correct?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373199/segmentation-fault-on-tf2_ros/) by [Kazunari Tanaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/70222/kazunari-tanaka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2021-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-04**:\

> I guess that these lines are incorrect.
> https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/1354c5663139e50ecafb888ae15aa113e9c3985d/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/message_filter.h#L486
> Because messages_ may be accessed before take the lock.

this reads more like a potential bug report than a question about usage.

I would recommend you post an issue on [the tracker](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues).

Do mention you've already posted on ROS Answers, and link to your ROS Answers question in your issue, and post a link to your issue here in a comment.

**Comment by [Kazunari Tanaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/70222/kazunari-tanaka/) on 2021-03-04**:
Thank you for the suggestion.
I try to make PR.
https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fix by
https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/386

---

Originally posted by [Kazunari Tanaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/70222/kazunari-tanaka/) with karma: 28 on 2021-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0